# How to transfer all mappings from Bundle to another bundle without overwriting it?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I have tried this but it overwrites the existing bundle:

```
Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
b1.putString("name", "Abraham");
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b2 = i.getExtras();
b1.putAll(b2);
```

Than i lose abraham...

Comment: There is no need of another bundle, you can directly send the previous bundle with or without adding other mappings into next **activity/fragment** by setting it  as **extra**  in intent for activity or as an **argument** in case of Fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is :
//Creating a  new Bundle

```
 Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
```

//Putting some value in that bundle

```
b1.putString("name", "Abraham");
```

//Creating a new Intent

```
Intent i = getIntent();
```

and here without assigning b1(bundle) to your intent like this

**i.putExtras(b1);**

//here you are getting a null bundle from intent.

Bundle b2 = i.getExtras();

// So you didn't get any bundle here snd getting an exception

```
b1.putAll(b2);
```

You just have to assign your bundle to intent. like mention above in bold.